# Why is Axios not working with eslint consistent return?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, eslint

Considering the following code (text book Axios get function), renderRedirect always triggers a consistent-return error. I have explored all of the code path for Axios I believe.

```
class Dashboard extends Component {

  renderRedirect = () => {
    const user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user'));
    if (user === null) {
      console.log('in');
      axios.get('/user')
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data));
          if (response.data.type === 'investor') {
            console.log('go to startups'); // LINE 17
            return <Redirect to="/startups" />;
          }
          console.log('go to investors');
          return <Redirect to="/investors" />;
        })
        .catch(() => {
          console.log('go to investors');
          return <Redirect to="/investors" />;
        });
    } else if (user.type === 'investor') {
      console.log('go to startups');  // LINE 28
      return <Redirect to="/startups" />;
    } else {
      console.log('go to investors');
      return <Redirect to="/investors" />;
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderRedirect()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Dashboard);
```

Why is that?

Also, looking at the console, I notice that both lines 17 and 28 are being called. Is there something I am missing out here?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Your first condition doesn't return anything on the synchronous path.

Comment: yet Axios does return values whatever the outcome of the request. What would be the best solution here then? I dont want to return anything until Axios has processed the reuqest. Thx

Comment: `get` is async; if you want to pretend it's synchronous then you have to `await`. IMO it'd be better to just accept that it's async and re-architect appropriately or you're going to freeze the UI during the request, which leads to poor UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your branch `if (user === null)`, you are not returning anything as `axios.get(...)` is your last statement.

Since `axios.get` would return a `Promise`, you won't be able to say `return axios.get` in a render method that expects synchronous results like React does.

In a case like this, you should use state (either `useState` hooks or use `setState`) and set the state to loading while you fetch through axios and, when done, set the state to the result you got (and return the Redirect instead of the loader).

Something like this:

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user'));
    if (user === null) {
      console.log('in');
      axios.get('/user')
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data));
          if (response.data.type === 'investor') {
            console.log('go to startups'); // LINE 17
            setRedirect("/startups");
          }
          console.log('go to investors');
          setRedirect("/investors");
        })
        .catch(() => {
          console.log('go to investors');
          setRedirect("/investors");
        });
    } else if (user.type === 'investor') {
      console.log('go to startups');  // LINE 28
      setRedirect("/startups");
    } else {
      console.log('go to investors');
      setRedirect("/investors");
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>{redirect === null ? "Loading user.type" : <Redirect to={redirect} />}</div>
  );
}
```